# Ошибка "type viewcontroller does not conform to protocol vkdelegate"

Tags: ios, swift, vkontakte-api

> type viewcontroller does not conform to protocol vkdelegate.

и правильно ли я делаю logout?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, VKDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        VK.configure(appID: "5720982", delegate: self)
    }

    func vkWillAuthorize() -> [VK.Scope] {
        //Called when SwiftyVK need autorization permissions.
        return [.offline] //an array of application permissions
    }

    func vkDidAuthorizeWith(parameters: Dictionary<String, String>) {
        let userId = parameters["user_id"]!

        let req = VK.API.Users.get([VK.Arg.userId: userId])
        req.httpMethod = .GET
        req.successBlock = { response in
            let id = response.array![0]["id"].intValue
            let firstName = response.array![0]["first_name"].stringValue
            let lastName = response.array![0]["last_name"].stringValue

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainPage") as! mainView
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

            print(id)
            print(firstName)
            print(lastName)
        }
        req.errorBlock = {
            error in print(error)
        }
        req.send()
    }

    func vkDidUnauthorize(id: Int) {
    /*    let logoutUrl = URL(string: "http://api.vk.com/oauth/logout")
        let request = URLRequest(url: logoutUrl!)
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)*/
        //Called when user is log out.
    }

    @IBAction func signInTouchUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
        VK.logIn()
    }

}
```

Comment: Нникогда не приводите код в виде скриншота. Код необходимо включать в вопрос в отформатированном виде и в минимальном размере, достаточном для анализа проблемы

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь Сейчас можете помочь?

Comment: моим комментарием я оказывал помошь проету. я не в теме вашей технологии. но совет продолжу. если вы разместили код. то скриншот этого кода надо убрать.

Comment: в протоколе vkdelegate есть определенный набор обязательных методов. у вашего класса они все должны присутствовать, чтобы он считался compliant. посмотрите каких не хватает и добавьте

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko откуда посмотреть?

Comment: проще всего сделать command+click на объявлении vkdelegate. ну либо например вот в гугле такое нашел http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SwiftyVK/1.3.1/Protocols/VKDelegate.html

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko на картинке же полный вид кода и там все есть что на ссылке. а что будет если сделать command+click на объявлении vkdelegate?

Comment: что это за библиотека, где ее посмотреть?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko https://github.com/WE-St0r/SwiftyVK. я нажал clean как на картинке и после этого не работает https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG98m.png

Comment: у vkDidUnauthorize нет никаких параметорв. а у вам там int

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko спасибо помог

Comment: принимайте ответ тогда

Answer (score 1):

У вас неправильная подпись в didUnauthorize - там не должно быть входного параметра (а у вас Int)

```
func vkDidUnauthorize()
```